# Speed of evaporation of tank

Tags: percentages

I am given $a$ and $b$ and the program should return the speed of evaporation(in percentages), if I know that the fluid from a tank evaporates to $a\%$ from the starting amount of the fluid, in $b$ months.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the notion of "speed of evaporation (in percentage)". Could you please define it?

Comment: Sorry, English is not my native language.. evaporation rate of fluid expressed in percentage

Comment: $a%$ is the amount evaporated (lost) or the amount remaining ?

Comment: the remaining amount

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

You have to define the law of evapouration.

Assuming a similar Newton's law of evaporative cooling.

$$ \dfrac{dy}{dt}=-k y \;, y=y_0 e^{-k t}$$

For given

$$y/y_0= 1-a/100, t= b$$

evaluate $k$ by taking logs.